# Converting MYSQL timestamp to ISO-8601 without timzone offset

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, date-conversion

I'm trying to use timeago  ( http://timeago.yarp.com/ ) and have found solutions for converting timestamps from MYSQL using php to ISO-8601.

```
date('c',strtotime($TimeStamp));
```

This works fine except im getting the timezone offset at the end

```
2011-07-10T08:46:50-**05:00**
```

what I want is `2011-07-10T08:46:50Z`

Does anyone have a solution or know why i'm getting the timezone offset?

Comment: http://os-code-web.blogspot.com/2011/04/15-top-php-coding-tutorials-tips-and.html

Comment: The 'Z' at the end *is* a timezone offset. It specifies the time zone UTC, its the same as 2011-07-10T08:46:50-0000 (or +0000, I suppose).

Answer (score 8):

You can do it directly in MySQL:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(yourfield, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s0Z')
```

There is a `GET_FORMAT(datetime, 'iso')` call as well, but that returns the format string for ISO 9075, which is not quite what you want. Since it doesn't do 8601 directly, you have to build the format string yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The 'c' will return the entire date, including the timezone offset. You will have to build it manually using the other options. Try this:

```
$time_stamp = time();
echo date('o-m-N',$time_stamp)."T".date('H:i:s',$time_stamp)."Z";
```

Comment: 'N' is for day of the week, 1 for Monday, 7 for Sunday. Wouldn't you want `o-m-d` or `Y-m-d` ?

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.types

```
const string ISO8601 = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sO";
```

You can use your own format:

```
date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z',strtotime($TimeStamp));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple for Open Graph

```
 date('Y-m-d\TH:i', strtotime('2015/09/24 08:46:50))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

`substr(date('c',strtotime($Timestamp)),0,-6).'Z';`